# Underline character is misbehaving in MINGW64 Bash

Tags: salesforcedx, git

I have been seeing this during the past month. By checking the standard CMD terminal I realized the issue is only happening in MINGW64 Bash:

MINGW64 Bash:
[image]

Win CMD:
[image]

I remember not having issues so something must have changed. I use the Bash terminal as my main tool because of the autocomplete functionality for sfdx in windows. Has anyone else seen this issue? Seems like an encoding issue  :(

After looking at the terminal's options for text interpretation I realized maybe it is using UTF-16 which is not offered as an option for some reason in MINGW64 Bash. All other encoding settings change the character but don't resolve to the underline character correctly. I also tried changing the locale (options are "en_US" and "C")

[image]

---

UPDATE:

(Current workarounds)

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2806#issuecomment-694469869

Comment: What happens if you try a command in PowerShell or cmd?

Comment: That is what is shown in the second image. No problem there

Comment: You might want to open an issue in https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but I don't currently have the commenting privilege. If you use "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" (what VScode uses) instead of "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe", you'll notice that the encoding works correctly, but you don't have all the same features you do with git-bash. I hope this helps someone figure out the issue as I'm at a loss as well.

Comment: I had forgotten this issue. I had already closed the issue I opened originally with SFDX CLI since it is a git thing. After that, I opened the issue with Git (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2806) and I now have a couple of workarounds. Seems that many people are in the same boat so I will leave it as open in hopes that is addressed fully to everyone's benefit.

Comment: @Glen De Marcos If your use case is running command-line utils (rather than developing apps), WSL is much easier to deal with nowadays than Cygwin or MinGW

Comment: @identigral I mainly work on apps but the sfdx autocomplete functionality only works with bash (that is why I brought this up). Now I am curious about WSL (never used it) - I'm not sure I will be able to install it on my work laptop but I surely will give it a go at home where I use ubuntu as my second OS (partitioned ssd)

Comment: @Glen De Marcos By "developing apps", I meant UNIX apps or apps that need POSIX compatibility that Cygwin/MinGW bring to the table. For Salesforce dev, the benefit of a UNIX shell boils down to CLI clients such as sfdx. WSL is the way to go there. sfdx can [autocomplete on Win](https://github.com/surajp/sfdx-powershell-autocomplete)

Comment: @identigral Gotcha, nope - my use case was limited to the Salesforce CLI. Thank you for sharing the PowerShell autocomplete repo! I might be able to get rid of MinGW altogether then...